# mp3 to ogg converter plugin for rhythmbox or banshee?

Tags: rhythmbox, music, plugins, music-player, ogg-vorbis

I like to convert all mp3,aac,wav files into ogg format. is there any plugins for rhythmbox or banshee that converts mp3 format into ogg formate automatically like itunes converts wma format into mp3.

> P.S All blackberries and android phones supports ogg format.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't convert from one lossy codec (MP3/AAC) to another (Ogg Vorbis). Converting the WAVs will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sound Converter can handle it, if you want to convert a large folder of music.

```
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

Comment: ahha..currently i am using sound-converter.But is there any plugins for rhythmbox r banshee that converts automatically to ogg format